# Apollo-client custom Headers and additional variables in Angular2

Tags: angular, typescript, xmlhttprequest, graphql, apollo-server

How to add custom headers and introduce additional custom variables in request body using npm apollo-client using Angular2. I wish to introduce an additional custom variable like default "Variables" object in request body along with custom headers in my graphQL query. I tried using applyMiddleware of createNetworkInterface.

Below is expected request body format:

```
{
   "query":"",
   "variables":"{}",
   "customVariable":"{}", //This is additional which wants to be introduced
   "operationName":""
}
```

Comment: What have you tried? Check out the docs here about middleware, they can modify the request any way you like: http://dev.apollodata.com/core/network.html#networkInterfaceMiddleware

Answer (score 0):

For one of our [Angular 2 examples](https://github.com/graphcool-examples/angular-apollo-instagram-example), we are adding a custom header like this:

```
networkInterface.use([{
  applyMiddleware (req, next) {
    if (!req.options.headers) {
      // Create the header object if needed.
      req.options.headers = {};
    }
    req.options.headers['x-graphcool-source'] = 'example:angular-apollo-instagram';
    next();
  },
}]);
```

Comment: How do I add an additional variable in request body ??

Comment: Its it a constant value that you want to add to the response? If not, what parameters do the new variables depend on?

Comment: Is it possible to inject a service into the middleware?